# How to skip values realtime database firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm checking last 100000 measurements of humidity and make chart, but on chart I want to show every 100th measurement, how can I modify this code to do this:

```
firebase.database().ref("Humidity").ref.orderByChild("time").limitToLast(100000).on("child_added",snapshot => {
    var a = snapshot.val().wartosc;
    var b = (new Date(snapshot.val().time *1000)).toLocaleString("pl-PL");
    
addData(myChart, b, a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
firebase.database().ref("Humidity")  //  Remove the extra ref here
.orderByChild("time")
.limitToLast(100000)
.on("value", snapshot => {           //  use value instead of child_added
  let index = 0;
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    if (index++ % 1000 === 0) {      //  check for every 1000th child
      var a = child.val().wartosc;
      var b = (new Date(child.val().time * 1000)).toLocaleString("pl-PL");
    }    
    addData(myChart, b, a);
  })
})
```

I've marked the main changes, but there may be some smaller changes needed too.